# Laravel | Testing

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-mail

I'm writing a http test for laravel 5.6.
After test I've got a warnig "Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers".

In a tested method I have a Mail send method. I've figured out, z the error comes from this method.

The code of send email is

```
public static function onRequestPasswordChangeSendResetLink(User $user, $resetUrl)
{
        Mail::to($user->email)
            ->send(new PasswordChange($user, $resetUrl));
}
```

What is wrong?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mailable class seems to have an `unclosed` section. Maybe `@section` without an `@endsection` or `@show` or some other directive that's unclosed

Comment: Ty. will check in a few hours.

Comment: There was 
@component('component-name')

without @endcomponent

Tahnk you, man!